# Placement Of JS Resource Via <r:external />

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I'm using the Resources plugin in Grails 2.0.1. The issue I'm having is getting a JavaScript resource specified using r:external to be placed after all of the other script previously declared using either r:require or r:external, all in the deferred disposition. Currently the resource specified using r:external it is being output in the location where the r:external tag is placed.

I have a layout file that contains an r:require tag to fetch some core resources:

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <r:require module="core" />
</head>
....
</html>
```

Then a GSP that includes another r:require tag followed by an r:external tag:

```
<head>
    ...
    <r:require module="forms" />
    <r:external dir="js" file="page-specific-resource.js" /> %{-- specifying disposition="defer" has no effect --}%
    ....
</head>
...
```

My expectation is each of the JavaScript resources I'm trying to include would be output in the deferred disposition with the core resources first, the forms resources next, and the page-specific resource last. The actual results are that the core and forms resources are output as expected in the deferred disposition, but the page-specific resource is output in head, where the r:external tag is placed (Specifying disposition="defer" seems to have no effect).

Is my expectation incorrect or is this a legitimate issue? Is there another way to specify page-specific resources (I'm trying avoid declaring these types of resources in the resource DSL) and have the positioned after all previously declared resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by Marc Palmer on the Grails User mailing list (http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Placement-Of-JS-Resource-Via-lt-r-external-gt-td4506074.html#none):

> I'm afraid your expectation is incorrect.
>
> r:external is just for rendering links where you invoke it.
>
> You need to declare your dependencies, or put your r:external at the
>   end of the page.
>
> Declaring modules for "functional areas" of your app is profitable. It
>   means you can also bundle them together if need be, or have fine
>   grained control and the page no longer needs to be aware of that.