# Grails Resources Plugin Reference resources outside the modules configuration

Tags: grails, module, resources, external

I have a requirement to load external (CMS provided sub-templates) assets where CSS and JS would end-up located either on top or bottom depending of the file type or the disposition attribute

Looking at this Post ([Placement Of JS Resource Via <r:external />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845513/placement-of-js-resource-via-rexternal)) I've discovered that it is not possible to place CSS and JS in LayoutResources if they aren't defined in the module configuration.

After reading the resource plugin code, I came with the idea of an additional tag that would dynamically create modules so they could be appended to the  . Here is a quick prototype, please don't judge the quality :)

The tag: 
`<r:cmsExternal url="/c/test.css" />`

The code behind (picked from ResourceProcessor class):

```
def cmsExternal = { attrs ->
    String disposition = attrs.remove('disposition')
    String url = attrs.remove('url')

    // Creating adhoc module
    ResourceModule module = grailsResourceProcessor.getModule(url) as ResourceModule
    // Prevent creating the same module/resource twice
    if(!module) {
        grailsResourceProcessor.defineModule(url)
        module = grailsResourceProcessor.getModule(url) as ResourceModule

        grailsResourceProcessor.resourceInfo.addDeclaredResource {
            ResourceMeta resourceMeta = new ResourceMeta(id: url, sourceUrl: url, workDir: grailsResourceProcessor.getWorkDir(), module:module)
            grailsResourceProcessor.prepareResource(resourceMeta, true)
            resourceMeta.disposition = disposition == 'head' || resourceMeta.processedFileExtension == 'css' ? 'head' : 'defer'
            module.resources = [resourceMeta]
            resourceMeta
        }
    }


    // Rendering adhoc module
    r.require(module: url)
}
```

It does work quite well but I was wondering if anyone had a better idea/method of doing this.